# vscode-extension: how to get the full hover information?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to get the full hover information in a vscode extension, like this
[image]

get the hover type

Comment: have you tried `vscode.executeHoverProvider`

Comment: I guess the OP actually wants the type information, not the hover popup as such. This question is not well formulated.

Comment: @rioV8 is this a valid api? I don't see it in [vscode-api](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api)

Comment: @MikeLischke yes, I want to get the type but I don't think the title is not well formulated . Since vscode has already generate the type, I want to get the hover info. It's useful for other use case btw

Comment: have you searched for the function name

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in an extension:

```js
const Uri = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri; 
const cursorPosition = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection.active;

const hover = await vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeHoverProvider', Uri, cursorPosition );
```

`hover` will be an array, you can drill down like `hover[0].contents[0].value` to get the actual hover message content.