# How can I get hover content in vscode extension development environment?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm trying to make a vscode extension because of the inconvenience, but I'm having trouble with it.
I want to get hover content, but I don't know what to do. Is there any way to get those texts?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDEKI.png)

I tried googling, reading docs, and finding posts but it's going nowhere. (Maybe lack of my English skills)

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77969480/836330 - I think it is what you want if you are trying to get that hover message, not create one yourself.

Comment: @Mark This is what I was looking for. Thank you! But I don't still get it yet...

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm currently having these problems:
First, I tried to reflect your answer in my code, but I'm having trouble with `hoverProvider`. If I make it as an async function, it doesn't work. Second, When i test my extension, a single hover keeps generating logs. Lastly, I don't know how to implement it. My goal is make an extension which makes interfaces give user detailed information. Like the image I posted, If you hover an extended interface, you can't get all types you need. I want to solve it.
here's my repo just in case you want: https://github.com/adaptersorg/ts-prettified-extended-interface

Comment: Okay, it looks like you don't want to get the hover information but you want to make a hoverProvider yourself.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72454283/can-i-show-an-image-in-a-hoverprovider/72465722#72465722 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67749752/how-to-apply-styling-and-html-tags-on-hover-message-with-vscode-api/67954180#67954180 .

Comment: Try `return new vscode.Hover(yourContent, new vscode.Range(position, position));`  You may have to return a `vscode.Hover` not just an object that looks like it.

Comment: Actually, my hoverProvider works very well(by returning an object). The reason why I tried to get the hover message was to find out the data of the interface that the user is hovering to show the user a detailed interface. I don't know if there's any other way. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [registerHoverProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages)